# Analysis on comparisons in a heap-like sorting algorithm

Tags: algorithms, sorting, trees, heaps, heap-sort

I've stumbled a heap-like sorting algorithm on the Internet as followed:

$\\$

For convenience, given a list of $2^n \; (n \in \mathbb{N^*})$ distinct numbers to be sorted increasingly.

**Step 1:** From the list, build a $P$-tree (to be defined) satisfying the **min-heap** property (Willard Zhan points out that this is actually a binomial heap), which costs $2^n-1$ comparisons. Go to **Step 2**.

**Step 2:** The root of the tree is the minimum on the tree at this time. So, pop it out and have $T$ trees remained. If $T > 1$, go to **Step 3**. If $T = 1$, go to **Step 2**. Otherwise, **stop**.

**Step 3:** By comparing their roots, **join** 2 of the remaining trees into 1 tree. The joining is done as followed: the larger root will be another child of the smaller root. The choice of 2 trees is done as followed: choose 2 trees with the least numbers of **root's children**. **Continue joining** until there is only 1 tree remained. One joining costs $1$ comparison, the whole step costs $T - 1$ comparisons ($T$ is taken from the previous step). Go to **Step 2**.

**$P$-trees** are defined as followed: $P_0$ is the $1$-node tree. For all positive integer $m$, $P_m$ is the tree having exactly $m$ first-class subtrees $P_0, ..., P_{m-1}$.

$\\$

I don't know this algorithm's proper name (if any). So I can't find any analysis on it, especially on its number of comparisons. I post this Question to ask for help on its name, its analysis, or some sources to read about them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your P-tree is exactly the [binomial heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_heap).

Comment: I've clarified Step 3 a bit more.

Comment: Look up the properties of the binomial heap and see whether you can analyze the algorithm yourself.

Comment: With the "infinity" node, I've managed to proof an upper bound: $\; \; \; n(2^n-2)+1$ comparisons. However, so far I have no meaningful lower bound or the tight upper bound.

Comment: I've proved a lower bound: $\; \; \; 2^{n+1}-3+\dfrac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}$ comparisons. Despite having no tight bounds, for now, I'm satisfied with the analysis and suspending my effort.

Comment: @VincentJ.Ruan $\Omega(2^n)$ comparisons is pretty bad. Are you sure you're right?

Comment: @adrianN Firstly, notice that the number of list elements is $2^n$. Secondly, I showed some bounds of the number of comparisons in worst-case (not in average-case), so actually it's not bad.

Comment: I've proved the tight upper bound: $\; \; \; (n-1)2^n + 1$. The tight lower bound is too tough for me.